# Return the different multiplicative combinations of a list of numbers in Python

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of numbers and I wish to return a 2D list, preferably ordered from biggest to smallest (although I can do this afterwards), of all the possible combinations of multiplication (to yield the product of the original list) using all the elements of the list, without duplicates. That is, if I have a list of [1, 2, 3] I want it to return

```
[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2], [6, 1], [6]]
```

without duplicates or equivalent lists, as seen above ([2,3] does not appear).

The reason for this is to find all the ways to multiply together the prime factorisation of a number. That is, from the prime factors of 24 (2, 2, 2, 3) I want it to return

```
[[3, 2, 2, 2], [4, 3, 2], [6, 4], [6, 2, 2], [8, 3], [12, 2], [24]]
```

I hope I have made myself clear, I wasn't sure how to phrase this question correctly.

Comment: When the inputs are all prime, this can be viewed as a multiset partition problem. Googling "multiset partitions" turns up a reference to Knuth volume 4, and a [LaTeX document/Haskell source file](http://sneezy.cs.nott.ac.uk/darcs/TMR/Issue8/Partitions.lhs) regarding the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the input of the algorithm be a single number?

Comment: What about `[6]`, or `[24]` in the second example?

Comment: As @tom10 said, you don't present any code. Either way, your 'problem' actually seems quite simple. Maybe it's not the most efficient one - but you could definitely use recursion (over every one list you get up untill the list consists only of 2 elements, then you need to get back to another second option and afterwards, delete duplicates).

Comment: @tom10: I've tried to permute all the possible lists of the numbers and then multiplying the first two, three, etc. to find the list. That is, I tried on paper but could not find a way to implement it. Either way I have to do this with a larger list and I'm looking for a fast way to find this.

Comment: @tobias_k: my apologies, 24 would be a number in the second example, I'll add it now. However, 6 would not, as every list within the list has a total product of 24 and has to be a "multiplicative permutation" of the original.

Comment: @Alessio_Am I meant `[6]` for the first example, as a product of all the numbers (6*1), just like `24` is for the second. Anyway, posting an answer in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: @ZachP I'm not sure what you mean. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Alessio_Am Basically, run through the list and multiply the first and second elements, then 2nd and 3rd, then 3rd and 4th and so on and every time create a new list and call that list to the same loop that creates that new lists and calls it again upon them up until there's only one element left. Append everything to a global list and that's it.

Comment: @ZachP Thank you for that, I will try it. I'm not the most proficient programmer but this points me in a good direction. Should I post the code when I finish it, or is that a topic for a question on code review? I'm quite new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this: Use two nested loops to multiply each number in the list with each other number, then recurse on that new list. This is not very efficient, as you will have tons of duplicate function calls (e.g. for multiplying the `3` in `(3, 2, 2, 2)` with any of the three `2`s, but this can be helped with a bit of memoization (unfortunately, this means we have to convert between lists and tuples a lot). Still, for larger inputs it's not very fast.

```
def memo(f):
    f.cache = {}
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in f.cache:
            f.cache[args] = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return f.cache[args]
    return _f

@memo
def mult_comb(factors):
    result = set()
    result.add(tuple(sorted(factors)))
    for i, f1 in enumerate(factors):
        factors2 = list(factors[:i] + factors[i+1:])
        for k in range(i, len(factors2)):
            factors2[k] *= f1
            result.update(mult_comb(tuple(factors2)))
            factors2[k] /= f1
    return result
```

Example:

```
>>> mult_comb((3,2,2,2))
set([(4, 6), (3, 8), (2, 12), (2, 3, 4), (24,), (2, 2, 6), (2, 2, 2, 3)])
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. I'll spend some time figuring out how it works before I implement it, but I did test it and it definitely works for the problem I am trying to solve.